# CSS positioning issue with frames

Tags: html, css

I want to set `background-color:#000` for the whole `.content` div. I have made a frame for an image and it wraps the image perfectly ( http://jsfiddle.net/Yuaq8/ ), but only if the position for the frame is set to `absolute`. In this case `.content` is not filled correctly.

If I remove the position property that belongs to `.pic-frame` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yuaq8/1/) , the `.content` div is filled, but the frame looks weird. How can I make the frame look like the one in the first fiddle, so it fills the entire .content div?

Comment: You should probably correct the spelling in your question title. I don't think "posiotioning" is a word, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:absolute` will remove your element from the flow. Use `position:relative` or `display:inline-block` instead on `.pic-frame`:

```
.pic-frame {
   display:inline-block;
   padding:12px;background-color: #DDD;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yuaq8/2/)

Comment: @riwette: Well, it does work, `.content` is filled correctly, isn't it ;)? Joking aside, you would need to set a fixed `width` and `height` or simply use the second solution I have given above (`display:inline-block`).

Comment: Thank you! `display:inline-block` is nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a width for .pic-frame.
[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ev7P8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set width to 200px in pic.frame div and remove the width and margin property from #pic div.

```
.pic-frame {
    width: 200px;
    padding:12px;background-color: #DDD;
}
#pic {
   height:200px;
   background-color: #999;
}
```